# PHP/JS Go back to previous page not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have a submit button which updates the data to the DB and then should go back to previous page. My problem here is when the user click on any other button and then click on submit button...it stays on the same page. How can I make it work ? so that it actually goes to previous page with diff url.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function goBack() {
    setTimeout("history.go(-1);", 5);
    }
  </script>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="button" onclick="goBack()">
```

Comment: it' not the way a user want's to do mostly. my word let your user experience like other web applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to modify your code to allow this, you could try using a button instead of an input:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function goBack() {
    setTimeout("history.go(-1);", 5);
    }
  </script>

<button type="button" onclick="goBack()">
Go Back
</button>

<button type="button">
Test Button
</button>
```

Comment: That will do the same exact thing as what I have right now.

Comment: I'm on chrome, and when I run the code snippet, I can press the test button a million times and go back to the previous page when I click the go back button.

Answer (score -1):

You may be are adding to the url a query string with other buttons, in which case your previous url is not what your expecting to be.
For example, your url is helloworld.com, and some button is adding #some to the url, resulting in helloworld.com#some ... In this case, the previous url would be helloworld.com without #some ... If this what you are getting, will have to take care of this.
I think you can maybe save the url you want to go back in a variable, and redirecting from there.

--- EDIT ---

In base to latest comments, i would suggest you to do this with AJAX, because i think you're trying to do somethig in the wrong way.
From the beginning, what your are getting is whats expected to be. The submit button executes a request to the form's url(if it's not defined, it's the same url where you are). So you are not in the same page, instead the page is being re loaded. In which case the previous URL is the same(or it seems to be the same).
With AJAX, in the most basic form, you can do something like this:

```
<script>
var submitElement = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

submitElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.open( "POST", url, true );
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-   urlencoded");
    ajax.send( params );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.history.back();
            }, 5);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm only showing you how to perform the ajax call from JS... From the PHP side, you have to take the form params to save them in the DB, but it's almost the same that you are doing right now, and i think you know how to do that.
Hope this clarify you the problem and the solution.

Comment: How would I save the url in a variable, if everytime I click on a button it refreshs the page....which means my variable will always be updated ??

Comment: Because you could define the url with PHP... For example, you can define a JS variable and populate it with php( var someVar = <?php echo $returnUrl ?> ) ... But thinking of further more, i understood that you are not preventing the submit event... I would suggest to add event listener instead of having a callback in the "onclink"... Example:

Comment: document.querySelector('input[type="sumbit"]').addEventListener('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); window.history.back(); })... But in this case you will need to perform the operation with AJAX instead of generating a new request.

Comment: How would i do that with ajax ? sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: yeah I could define the url in php, but the url is dynamic. for example: page.php?index=10 and user could come from index=...any number

Comment: @VHDLprog please check the edited answer, and let me know if that answer is useful for you. REgards!